# UIDatePicker shows fine in iPhone but it doesn't in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm showing a UIDatePicker in an UITableViewController and it looks fine. When a segue the same controller as a popover the UIDatePicker doesn't look good.

I put the UIDatePicker inside a UITableViewController.

This one is from the iPhone[image]
And this one is from the iPad
[image]

Comment: How are you creating and displaying your picker? Show some code.

Comment: Just a heads up, you can take much cleaner screenshots with Command+S in the iOS Simulator.

Comment: I create the picker using the Interface Builder. I created a custom cell with a picker inside. Is the same ViewController for both ipad and iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Your iPad picker looks just fine. I think there is another view covering a part of it. Try this in the debugger:

```
po [self.view recursiveDescription]
```

and see if you can find the view in this way.

Comment: Asking for my own curiosity: what kind of view would cover the day field and part of the month, but not the horizontal lines highlighting the current selection?  Could a view have wormed its way in between those two layers?

Comment: Yes, weird indeed. You still did not show how you display and create the picker.

Comment: The picker is inside a custom cell and is the same view controller for both ipad and iphone.

Comment: So did you find an extra view with the above method?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this problem when all of the following are true:

- The date picker is inside a table view cell
- The table view controller is being presented modally
- The modal presentation style is 'Form sheet'
- The device is an iPad

The best workaround I have found is to change the modal presentation style. 'Page sheet' works fine, for example.

This seems like an OS bug.